# Java Classes that extend abstract classes action on button click

Tags: java, inheritance, abstract-class, extends

I'm trying to find an example of a class extending an abstract class in java that is intended to perform an action based on radio button selected and button clicked.

Instructions:

Create Transaction form to manage account balance.

1. Create transaction Options:

   Deposits add to balance
   Checks subtract from balance
       if balance > check then subtract check from balance
       else Display Insufficient Funds Message
       and Subtract Service Charge ($10) from balance
   Service Charge ($10) subtract from balance
2. Use Abstract Class Transaction to create classes:

   class Deposit
   class ServiceCharge
   class Check
   override the abstract function calculateBalance() in each class to perform the appropriate calculations on balance
       throw an Exception in class Check.calculateBalance()

I am to use the following abstract class:

```js
public abstract class Transaction {

  /**
  The Transaction class simulates a bank account.
  */

  static final double SERVICE_CHARGE = 10.0;
  double transactionamount = 0.0;

  static double balance = 0.0; // Account balance
  static double totalDeposits = 0.0;
  static double totalChecks = 0.0;
  static double totalServiceCharges = 0.0;
  static int numberDeposits = 0;
  static int numberChecks = 0;
  static int numberServiceCharges = 0;

  public Transaction() {
    transactionamount = 0.0;
  }

  public Transaction(double amount) {
    this.transactionamount = amount;
  }

  public Transaction(String str) {
    transactionamount = Double.parseDouble(str);
  }

  public void deposit(double amount) {
    balance += amount;
  }

  public void deposit(String str) {
    balance += Double.parseDouble(str);
  }

  static public double getBalance() {
    return balance;
  }

  abstract void calculateBalance() throws Exception;

}
```

Here's what I have that I'm trying to get to work:

The class extending Transaction class is listed first, my example is Check class.  I'm trying to set up my calculate button and transaction menu selection to pass information based on radio button selection and text field data.

```html
package Assignment5;

public class Check extends Transaction {

 public double checksBalance(double check) // makes alterations to Transaction variables once information is passed from text field.
    {
  check = transactionamount;
  totalChecks = check + totalChecks; // increases total amount in checks.
  balance = check + totalDeposits - totalChecks - totalServiceCharges;
  return check;
  
  
    }
 public int checks() {
  return numberChecks++;  // increases number of checks written.
  }
 
 
 @Override
 void calculateBalance() throws Exception {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  
 }
 
}

public class TypePanel extends JPanel
  {

      public String deposit, check, service; 
  
   JRadioButton depositButton;
   JRadioButton checkButton;
   JRadioButton serviceButton;
         ButtonGroup radioButtonGroup;

   public TypePanel()  //
   {

    setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 1));  // Panel Layout

    depositButton = new JRadioButton("Deposit", true);  // Radiobuttons listed here. 
          checkButton = new JRadioButton("Check");
          serviceButton = new JRadioButton("Service Charge");
          

          radioButtonGroup = new ButtonGroup();
    radioButtonGroup.add(depositButton);
          radioButtonGroup.add(checkButton);
          radioButtonGroup.add(serviceButton);

          

          add(depositButton);
    add(checkButton);
    add(serviceButton);
   }
   
   public void GetTotals() 
      {
    
         if (checkButton.isSelected())
      {
         
         Transaction.transactionamount = AmountPanel.amountEntered;
      }
      
   
  }


public class AmountPanel extends JPanel {
   public static Object amountEntered;
   public String amountInput;
   private JLabel amountLabel;
      private String defaultText;
      private JTextField amountTextField;
      

   public AmountPanel()
     {
      setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 1)); // Panel Layout.

      amountLabel = new JLabel("Enter Amount");

      amountTextField = new JTextField(6);

      defaultText = "0"; // Default value placed in textfields within this panel.

      amountTextField.setText(defaultText);

      add(amountLabel);
      add(amountTextField);
         }

     public double GetAmount()  
     {
   double amountEntered;

   amountInput = amountTextField.getText();
   amountEntered = Double.parseDouble(amountInput);



   return amountEntered;
  }
 }
```

I didn't include all of my code, but I'm trying to get the amount entered from the text field to the methods located in the Check class so they will then in turn affect the variables in the Transaction class.  I don't think I'm doing this in the best way though.

Comment: Why not first try to do this yourself and see what you can come up with? You've nothing to lose in the attempt and all to gain. Then if you are successful -- great, you've done well and on your own too, and if you fail, then no big problem since you can come back here, ask a new question, a **much more specific and answerable question**, and will likely get a great and prompt answer.

Comment: Also, your instructions pretty much spell out exactly what you must do. With these instructions and pretty much any intro to Java book or tutorial on abstract classes, you should be able to at least start on your own. Again, I urge you to please do exactly this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any class you write to extend Transaction should either be abstract itself or at the very least implement void calculateBalance() throws Exception; . The point of "abstract" is to implement the methods that will be common among the derived classes and then implement the methods that will be different within the derived class. It's the same as extending any other class really, with the exception that if you're extending an abstract class as a non-abstract class, you must implement any of the abstract methods from the abstract class.

You can replace some of the other functions, if necessary, by simply re-implementing them, and you can force them to use the implementation of the extended class when called by adding the @Override annotation to the method.

Good reads: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/abstract.html